# ProgressDialog message text different from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Hope someone can help?

I'm fairly new to Android development, but I think I've tried everything.

In my app the message text size and colour is different between a ProgressDialog and AlertDialog. I'm trying to have uniform styling across the app.

I'm using the app compact theme and have hunted all over to try and find a way to override the ProgressDialog text size for a message and can't. I've even tried doing it in code using setTextSize on android.R.id.message and its doesn't play. It find the TextView but won't change the size.

I've also tried using setContentView and whilst I can make that work I loose a lot of the methods like setMesaage. Also tired setView but that gets killed by onCreate of the ProgressDialog.

Seems like a lot to do to implement a custom dialog just to change the text size.

Would anyone have any thoughts please and thank you?

I'm using api version 22 in android studio 2. I don't really have any sample code to share as I'm trying to use the standard ProgressDialog init sequence.

Stuart

Comment: I know you have a general question but it's always useful to provide as much detail as you can.  So platform specifics for both dev and testing, platform versions, sample code, etc...

Comment: Thanks, will update my question now. :)

Answer (score 0):

android.R.id.message is not the correct reference. It should be (your.package.name).R.id.message. You should fix the import in your file.

Comment: Is that even if I'm getting the TextView on an android component like ProgressDialog? I've used android.R etc on an AlertDialog before and it was fine.

Comment: Are you using a custom view for your ProgressDialog - if yes, then it should be the R class for your package - same with AlertDialog. But maybe for the AlertDialog, you used the standard android supplied AlertDialog.
If you're not using custom views for ProgrssDialog, switch to a custom view as they are much easier to modify.